# Syntax error cant find the error

Tags: javascript

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");

var computerChoice = Math.random();

if (computerChoice <= 0.33) {
computerChoice = "rock";
} 
else if(computerChoice > 0.34 && computerChoice < 0.66) {
computerChoice = "paper";
} 
else {
computerChoice = "scissors";
}

var compare=function(choice1,choice2){

if(choice1 === choice2){
    return "The result is a tie!";
}

else if(choice1 === "rock"){

    if(choice2 ==="scissors"){
        return "rock wins";
    }
    else{
        return "paper wins";    
    }
}

else if(choice1 ==="paper"){

    if(choice2 ==="rock"){
        return "paper wins";    
    }   

    else{
        return "scissors wins";    
    }
}

else{
    if(choice2 === paper){
        return "scissors wins';    
    }
    else{
        return "rock wins";    
    }
}
};

compare(userChoice,computerChoice);

console.log(compare);
```

I cant seem to see the problem with my code , I've been trying to solve it for a while but it keep saying Syntax error : invalid or unexpected token.
I've only started learning `javascript`, the website I'm trying to learn from only gives me very little information of how to finish this. Instead of helping, all it does is keep printing out `Syntax error : invalid or unexpected token` for the last hour.

Comment: Notice that towards the end of the code you posted, the color coding gets weird?

Comment: TYPO. Line `return "scissors wins';` should either be `"scissors wins"` or `'scissors wins'`

Comment: THANK YOU oh my god how did i not see that

Comment: try F12(debugging)  on IE, this gives you more detailed info

Comment: `paper` should be a string here: `choice2 === paper`

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing single quote with double quote after `scissors wins`. Replace this:

```
return "scissors wins';
```

by this:

```
return "scissors wins";
```